# Failed to leapp upgrade the RHEL server from 7.9 to 8.4 using custom repository not using Redhat satellite or Redhat Subscriotion

Tags: rhel7

I need your help to sort out my leapp preupgrade command issue. Our plan is to upgrade the RHEL server from 7.3 to 8.4. Our Proposed way is first we need to upgrade rhel server from 7.3 to 7.9 and then we try to upgrade the RHEL OS from 7.9 to 8.4. This all using custom repositories not using subscription-manager or redhat satellite server. We are able to upgrade the RHEL server from 7.3 to 7.9 without any issue. when we try to upgrade rhel 7.9 to 8.4 it is getting issue. Below we have tried.